# How to attach IAM policy globally to all buckets

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

As part of security checks we are required to prevent access to s3 buckets using insecure HTTP. At the moment we are having to go through all our repositories and attach a policy to each individual bucket. Is there a way to attach this policy only once at a global level for all buckets?

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "www_bucket_policy" {

    statement {
      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = ["*"]
      }
      resources = [
        aws_s3_bucket.static_ui.arn,
            "${aws_s3_bucket.static_ui.arn}/*"
      ]
      effect = "Deny"
      actions = [
        "s3:*"
      ]
      condition {
        test = "Bool"
        variable = "aws:SecureTransport"
        values = [
          "false"
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not certain this can be done via Terraform, but you can do it at the account level directly via AWS. https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/block-public-access/ "If you want to restrict access to all existing buckets in your account, you can enable Block Public Access at the account level."

Comment: @ceejayoz The OP's Policy bans access over plaintext HTTP.  BPA bans public access, which is something completely different.

Comment: @user3553031 Thanks for catching that; I misread the question.